# Non destructive subsequence-except in lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, subsequence

I know subseq in lisp return a subsequence through a range. Is there anything which will return the subsequence except that range and should be non-destructive? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: There's nothing built-in. Get the subsequence before the range and the subsequence after it, and then concatenate them with `nconc`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it for any sequence with `concatenate` and `subseq`:

```
(defun sequence-except (sequence start end)
  (concatenate (sequence-type sequence)
               (subseq sequence 0 start)
               (subseq sequence end)))
```

The following should be enough to determine the type of the input sequence for bit-vectors, strings, etc:

```
(defun sequence-type (sequence)
  (etypecase sequence
    (list 'list)
    (array `(array ,(array-element-type sequence) (*)))))
```

Tests:

```
(loop for test in (list
                   #*10101001
                   "abcd"
                   '(0 3 2)
                   nil
                   #(1 2 3 4)
                   (make-array 4
                               :adjustable t
                               :fill-pointer T
                               :initial-contents
                               '(a b c d)))
      collect (concatenate (sequence-type test) test))
```

Answer (score 0):

can't you just:

```
(defun seq-drop-subseq (SEQ START &optional END)
  (if END
      (nconc (seq-take START) (seq-drop END))
    (seq-take START)))
```

edit: had to go look.  `remove` does it.